# how to convert google xml feeds into collection of java objects

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, google-contacts-api

I am trying to convert the google `xml/atom` feeds into collection of object(i.e. POJOs).But I read some documentation of `JAXB` and `Xstream`.But these have simple XML documents as compared to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed gd:etag="&quot;Q3k8fDVSLyt7I2A9XRVaFUgKRgE.&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <id>yogeshseralia98@gmail.com</id>
 <updated>2015-08-14T11:02:32.774Z</updated>
 <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
 <title>Yogesh Seralia's Contacts</title>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/full/batch"/>
 <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/full?max-results=25"/>
 <author>
  <name>Yogesh Seralia</name>
  <email>yogeshseralia98@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
 <generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>25</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
 <entry gd:etag="&quot;SXk8fDVSLyt7I2A9XRRWFU4IRww.&quot;">
  <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/base/14e49898ff5258e</id>
  <updated>2015-03-05T05:08:08.774Z</updated>
  <app:edited xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">2015-03-05T05:08:08.774Z</app:edited>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <title>World of Level Design</title>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/14e49898ff5258e" gd:etag="&quot;XR1hbn4UfCt7I2A0MFUmRAh8G3IzfnwscRo.&quot;"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/full/14e49898ff5258e"/>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/yogeshseralia98%40gmail.com/full/14e49898ff5258e"/>
  <gd:name>
   <gd:fullName>World of Level Design</gd:fullName>
   <gd:givenName>World</gd:givenName>
   <gd:additionalName>of Level</gd:additionalName>
   <gd:familyName>Design</gd:familyName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="alex@worldofleveldesign.com" primary="true"/>
  <gContact:website href="http://www.google.com/profiles/118120233525415358578" rel="profile"/>
 </entry>
<feed>
```

This feed is generated from google servers using `Contacts API v3`.But using only hitting REST API and not used Google Sdks for it.

Here I can't make a POJO with a variable name as `gContact:website` to map `<gContact:website>` xml element.Please guide me if i am mistaken.

Comment: Have you considered using Apache Abdera?

Comment: Yp ! it has very vast features,but i got one more solution i.e. I changed my  scope of Google Contacts from `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/` to `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json` and here now from here data is sent in to json and it can be easily converted to POJOs. BUT I will surely make a try with your suggestion. UPVOTE to yor suggestion